# Error in BIRT when doing request Eclipse with query doing

Tags: mysql, birt

I am a novice programmer and I have a problem in creating a report on birt.When I make a request for navicat everything works fine but when I try to make a request for birt I get an error

Comment: the problem occurs when a new variable is created.Error occurs in this peace of code "SET @Date='2019.05.22'"

Comment: show your code and exact error you are facing